# How to define type of a callback input that depends on the inputted event name

Tags: reactjs, typescript

For example if I had something like:

```
type eventType = "ready" | "buzz";
type eventTypeReadyInput = {appIsReady: string};
interface mysdk {
  on:(event: eventType, cb: (input: eventTypeCallbackInput) => void) => void
}
mysdk.on("ready", (readyInput) => {})
```

How can I make it so that ready input is typed based on the eventType instead of having to declare it like this:

```
mysdk.on("ready", (readyInput: eventTypeReadyInput) => {});
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: what type should `input` be if you pass in `"buzz"`?

Comment: You can make `on` a generic function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxY78W); does that meet your needs?  (Check it against your use cases).  If so then I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a lookup Mapping type, that gives us a relationship between each of the `Event` type, and it's corresponding `input`
And then using generic function you can conditionally type the event and it's callback input.

```
type eventType = "ready" | "buzz";
type eventTypeReadyInput = {appIsReady: string};
type eventTypeBuzzInput = {appIsBuzzing: string};

type EventLookup =  {
    "ready": eventTypeReadyInput,
    "buzz": eventTypeBuzzInput
}


interface SDK {
  on:<EType extends keyof EventLookup>(event: EType, cb: (input: EventLookup[EType]) => void) => void
}

declare let mysdk: SDK;

mysdk.on("ready", (readyInput) => { readyInput.appIsReady })
mysdk.on("buzz", (readyInput) => { readyInput.appIsBuzzing })
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBBBuEDtgBVzQLxQEQCcIEMATELKAH2wCMBXAL1qwG4BYAKFEhniVUgCUCxAJIIw1YFEwBvfGDBCAzgKIgAXFAXAcASwQBzAL4t2aLohRoAQnVoixE6bPkLr9XXvWad%20o2zYdoAFFuYAAZAHtwgGtqMEkoKCk2BITcQRJ1OHNeCGVhUXEAGmSUrBp6LEyQnNdbAuA2Az9WNl1gCBwAM3wAY2gAZQARAGlEkvCEVQAeQJyYAA92hEIFKCiIEHDOqGDzCOjYgD4ACiykdVm0QqgeynVj3XsLkP2YsABtS8gAXQBKSUOUFg4W0hH%206EBwNBjWahAgPQANvg8FAERAJABbEAKQhRdRDYbGNhYnFRAB0E2OaRUWGuxzwKjs4nBgKkUAZ%20XsZKcijyICgBl%20xOxuIpCCp5QYdI5ICZwBZiXZ6Tl3Lkilq7gFvyAA)